# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session error in Selenium automation tests using ChromeDriver Chrome with Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Getting "No such session exception" while running selenium in my pipeline.
I find many solutions related it but none worked for me. Any assistance or idea?
Exception trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Linux 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:25:02.294Z'
System info: host: 'chaos', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa876..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 75.0.3770.100, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: e25db38f6fb8cdaac6d4a699504c608f
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor129.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
```

I have checked in code; there is no driver.close() or driver.quit() is used.Tests are running successfully sometime and sometimes are failing.

Can any one help me for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Linux 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:25:02.294Z'
System info: host: 'chaos', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.38*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.38*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v65-67**

- Presumably you are using *chrome=79.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v79.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 79**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.9.1* of *2018-02-07T22:25:02.294Z* which is almost **2** years older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_121** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between *JDK v8u121* , *Selenium Client v3.9.1* , *ChromeDriver v2.38* and the *Chrome Browser v79.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u232](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.