# Selenium invalid session id from loop with current webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iteration

I'm getting an error for starting multiple driver.get commands in an loop. I have looked at people with similar problems i.e [org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session error in Selenium automation tests using ChromeDriver Chrome with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59998534/org-openqa-selenium-nosuchsessionexception-no-such-session-error-in-selenium-au) but the problem there was the jdk version, chrome version and such. I can start one get command for each instance of webdriver so i don't belive it's a version of my jdk,chromedriver or selenium that's the problem.

```
String[] referenceID = reference;
        String[] commandID = command;
        String url = "https://"+website;
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(referenceID));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(commandID));
        System.out.println("Done");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\selenium\\libs\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
        
        
        long waitTime = 0;
        
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int times = gui.getTestAmount();
        int i = 0;
        
        boolean reset = false;
        driver.get(url);
        while(times != 0) {
            if(reset) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(9000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                driver.get(url);
                reset = false;  
            }
            
            if(commandID[i].equals("Click")) {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(referenceID[i])).click();
                System.out.println("Clicked");
            }
            if (commandID[i].equals("Text")) {
                System.out.println("testing text");
                String s = referenceID[i];
                String id = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(' '));
                System.out.println(id);
                String content = s.substring(s.indexOf(' ') + 1);
                System.out.println(content);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(id)).sendKeys(content);
            }
            if (commandID[i].equals("Wait")) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(referenceID[i])*1000);
                    waitTime += (Integer.parseInt(referenceID[i])*1000);
                    System.out.println("Waited");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Waited done");
            }
            i++;
            if(i>referenceID.length-1) {
                System.out.println("in reset");
                reset = true;
                driver.close();
                i=0;
                times--;
            }
        }
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-E1N87PDH', ip: 'XXXXXXXX(edited out myself)', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 83.0.4103.116, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\marti\AppData\Loca...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:56414}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: ea7286c558f6d6969eb16fcb410e68af
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:277)
    at data.getInfo.print(getInfo.java:39)
    at gui.gui.lambda$5(gui.java:153)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: If you are closing the same instance of driver and trying use it again . It will throw the exception .

Comment: But using close only ends the current web-page the driver is focused on?

Comment: Can you post how you are initializing the driver instance before start of while loop in above example

Comment: You need to refine the logic . Calling the close on the only existing window will destroy the session .  One approach can be open new tab every time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829329/how-to-open-a-link-in-new-tab-chrome-using-selenium-webdriver/34831289 and close that tab. once you are ready to quite. Call quit() it will close all open browser windows..

Answer (score 1):

```
  /**
   * Close the current window, quitting the browser if it's the last window currently open.
   */
  void close();
```

You don't need to close between gets -- each get will reload the contents of the browser window.

Comment: Thank you, i never thought of that. Now it works perfectly. Now i only get an empty window that never changes but that's probably a minor bug. But a part of my program is to measure performance of websites would a refresh of the page take up the same performance as a new window connecting to it? I'm assuming not closing the driver and just refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the issue was initiating driver inside if statement. Can you try giving `driver.get(url);` before `while(times != 0)`

Believe driver is getting inactive after if block was completed so that other elements are not responding. [Refer this for more solutions](https://www.techtravelhub.com/nosuchsessionexception-in-selenium/)

Comment: Yeah i tried that but i get the same error, the first get mothod works fine but it's the second one that raises the error.

Comment: Are you attempting to perform cross browser testing?

Comment: Yeah that's the idea.