# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Unable to find session with ID error testing with Behat/Mink and Selenium2Driver in docker container

Tags: docker, selenium, symfony, selenium-chromedriver, behat

I'm trying to test a Symfony3 web application with [Behat/Mink](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/index.html) and [Selenium2Driver](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/drivers/selenium2.html) so that I can test Javascript functionallity too.

The application runs in a docker container, so I added a new docker container for selenium-hub and chrome as described [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium):

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.5' # Docker Engine release 17.12.0+

networks:
    servicesnet:
      driver: bridge

services:
   apache:
      build:
         context: './apache2'
      container_name: apache-service
      ports:
         - "80:80"
         - "443:443"
      tty: true
      networks:
         - servicesnet
      volumes:
         - ${HOST_APACHE_CONFIG}:/etc/apache2
         - ${HOST_PAGES_PATH}:/var/www/localhost/htdocs

   selenium-hub:
      image: selenium/hub:4.0.0-alpha-6-20200730
      container_name: selenium-hub
      ports:
         - "4444:4444"
      networks:
         - servicesnet

   chrome:
      image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-alpha-6-20200730
      volumes:
         - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      depends_on:
         - selenium-hub
      environment:
         - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      networks:
         - servicesnet
```

When I run `docker-compose up` it outputs for the new containers:

```
chrome          | 2020-08-12 07:36:19,917 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/selenium.conf" during parsing
chrome          | 2020-08-12 07:36:19,918 INFO supervisord started with pid 7
selenium-hub    | 2020-08-12 07:36:19,297 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/selenium-grid-hub.conf" during parsing
selenium-hub    | 2020-08-12 07:36:19,298 INFO supervisord started with pid 7
selenium-hub    | 2020-08-12 07:36:20,301 INFO spawned: 'selenium-grid-hub' with pid 10
selenium-hub    | Starting Selenium Grid Hub...
selenium-hub    | 2020-08-12 07:36:20,311 INFO success: selenium-grid-hub entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
selenium-hub    | 07:36:20.588 INFO [LoggingOptions.getTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
selenium-hub    | 07:36:20.589 INFO [LoggingOptions.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
selenium-hub    | 07:36:20.607 INFO [EventBusOptions.createBus] - Creating event bus: org.openqa.selenium.events.zeromq.ZeroMqEventBus
selenium-hub    | 07:36:20.638 INFO [BoundZmqEventBus.<init>] - XPUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4442, advertising as tcp://172.28.0.3:4442], XSUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4443, advertising as tcp://172.28.0.3:4443]
selenium-hub    | 07:36:20.676 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://172.28.0.3:4442 and tcp://172.28.0.3:4443
selenium-hub    | 07:36:20.680 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
selenium-hub    | 07:36:20.681 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.lambda$new$2] - Bus started
chrome          | 2020-08-12 07:36:21,136 INFO success: xvfb entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
chrome          | 2020-08-12 07:36:21,136 INFO success: fluxbox entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
chrome          | 2020-08-12 07:36:21,136 INFO success: vnc entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
chrome          | 2020-08-12 07:36:21,137 INFO success: selenium-node entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
selenium-hub    | 07:36:21.308 INFO [Hub.execute] - Started Selenium hub 4.0.0-alpha-6 (revision 5f43a29cfc): http://172.28.0.3:4444
chrome          | 07:36:21.774 INFO [LoggingOptions.getTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
chrome          | 07:36:21.775 INFO [LoggingOptions.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
chrome          | 07:36:21.791 INFO [EventBusOptions.createBus] - Creating event bus: org.openqa.selenium.events.zeromq.ZeroMqEventBus
chrome          | 07:36:21.829 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://selenium-hub:4442 and tcp://selenium-hub:4443
chrome          | 07:36:21.857 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
chrome          | 07:36:21.859 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.lambda$new$2] - Bus started
chrome          | 07:36:22.121 INFO [NodeServer.execute] - Reporting self as: http://172.28.0.5:5555
chrome          | 07:36:22.175 INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding Chrome for {"browserName": "chrome"} 8 times
chrome          | 07:36:22.298 INFO [NodeServer.execute] - Started Selenium node 4.0.0-alpha-6 (revision 5f43a29cfc): http://172.28.0.5:5555
chrome          | 07:36:22.302 INFO [NodeServer.execute] - Starting registration process for node id ff0154a7-ed4b-438a-887c-0a7f3a988cb4
selenium-hub    | 07:36:22.355 INFO [LocalDistributor.refresh] - Creating a new remote node for http://172.28.0.5:5555
selenium-hub    | 07:36:22.763 INFO [LocalDistributor.add] - Added node ff0154a7-ed4b-438a-887c-0a7f3a988cb4.
selenium-hub    | 07:36:22.770 INFO [Host.lambda$new$0] - Changing status of node ff0154a7-ed4b-438a-887c-0a7f3a988cb4 from DOWN to UP. Reason: http://172.28.0.5:5555 is ok
chrome          | 07:36:22.774 INFO [NodeServer.lambda$execute$0] - Node has been added
```

Then I have the next method for every test:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver;
use Behat\Mink\Mink;
use Behat\Mink\Session;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

abstract class BaseControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Client
     */
    protected $client;
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    public function visitUri($uri)
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient();
        $pass = $this->client->getKernel()->getContainer()->getParameter('http_basic_auth_pass');
        $host = 'localhost'; // I've tried several things here (like 172.28.0.5:5555)

        $driver = new Selenium2Driver('chrome');
        $mink = new Mink(array(
            'chrome' => new Session($driver)
        ));
        $driver->setTimeouts(['page load' => 900000]);

        $mink->setDefaultSessionName('chrome');

        $this->session = $mink->getSession();

        $this->session->visit('http://user:' . $pass . '@' . $host . $uri);
    }
}
```

And I call this method from a specific test:

```php
    public function testClickOnSearch()
    {
        $this->visitUri(/mi-custom-uri);
        $page = $this->session->getPage();

        $this->session->wait(
            200000,
            "typeof jQuery !== 'undefined'"
        );

        $page->findButton('Buton text')->click();
        $this->assertContains('my-custom-uri-2', $this->session->getCurrentUrl());
    }
```

but I never get the session started. If I go to `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/url` I see this error message:

> "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Unable to find session with ID: url\nBuild info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-6', revision: '5f43a29cfc'\nSystem info: host: 'fca78c7f81e6', ip: '172.28.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-42-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_252'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown"

And executing the test, after 200 seconds this error is thrown:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function click() on null

I'm sure something is missing but don't know what. Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Unable to find session with ID: url\n
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-6', revision: '5f43a29cfc'\n
System info: host: 'fca78c7f81e6', ip: '172.28.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-42-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_252'\n
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session which gets reflected in the logs as:

```
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Hence moving forward you see the error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function click() on null
```

and the most probhable cause is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v84.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 84.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v84.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session error in Selenium automation tests using ChromeDriver Chrome with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59998534/org-openqa-selenium-nosuchsessionexception-no-such-session-error-in-selenium-au/59999386#59999386)

Comment: Thank you, as you can see I'm just using the docker-compose suggested in https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium. How do you think I should proceed?

Comment: Don't you have any idea?

Comment: At least now I know where the issue is, but I am using the docker version of selenium in kubernetes and this keeps happening

Answer (score 0):

Found you using selenium inside docker container. Than you can try environment variable SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT=999999